# make file target run everytime whether .env file change or not

Tags: makefile

I understand the Makefile and created a simple Makefile:

```
echo: .env
    @echo "ENV CHANGED"
```

When I run the `make` it will print the echo every time when .env is changed. But it runs every time. What I am doing wrong.

Comment: `echo` is a phony target, and you should specify it as such (`.PHONY: echo`), so you saying the target depends on .env.  Make doesn't know when it was last build so it will build it every time.  You could create a file track when you last build this target.

Comment: The next problem is that .env is presumably a directory and you may want to track changes to files.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [empty file](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Empty-Targets.html) to track the last time the `echo` target ran:

```
.PHONY: echo 

echo: .env.touch

%.touch: %
    @echo "ENV CHANGED"
    touch $@
```

and example run:

```
$ make
ENV CHANGED
$ make
$ touch .env
$ make
ENV CHANGED
```

`.env` is presumably a directory.  It may not change if it's content does in which case you need to track the content of the file.   You could also write a suitable shell code; here find will look for any files newer than the `.env` directory and just return the first result as an indicator:

```
echo:
    changes=`find .env -newer .env -print -quit`;\
    if [ -n "$$changes" ];\
    then\
        echo "ENV CHANGED";\
        touch .env;\
    fi
```